# Verbose Boot after crashed program on Macbook Pro

Tags: mac, snow-leopard

I had recently installed Google Drive on my Macbook Pro running Snow Leopard 10.6.8 but it kept crashing my computer to the point where it would not start.

I deleted Google Drive in Single User Mode, and  am still getting blue screen or the grey screen with the turning wheel, I suspect from all the forced restarts.

I have tried resetting the pram, smc, repaired the drive in disc utility and reinstalled Snow Leopard from the disc. Should I try resetting in verbose mode?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue with Snow Leopard and Google Drive. I've seen this many times before and deleting Google Drive completely from the Macbook usually fixes it without issue. When you reinstalled Snow Leopard did you do a clean install or was it truly just a reinstall. If you really got rid of Google Drive and it's not booting sounds like something may have happened to the hard drive. I would try a clean restore of Snow Leopard before taking any hardware action. :)

Comment: Cool, thanks. No, it wasnt a clean install, i dont have the past few weeks backed up so its my last resort :) anything else you think i can try first?

Comment: Just double check and make Google Drive is completely gone. Outside of that, you may need to take it to an Apple Store to have them run their hard drive diagnostics to let you know what the exact issue is. But from my experience a clean install would fix it if the OS was corrupted by the unexpected restarts.